# How to compute the probability $P(X<t<Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with known distribution, $t$ is a constant.
How to compute the probability $\mathbb P(X<t<Y)$?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb yes, they are independent.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $$P(X<t<Y)=P(X<t)P(t<Y)=F_X(t-)(1-F_Y(t))$$ Where is the problem?

Comment: Can I interpret in this way: $P(X<t<Y)=1−P(X>t)−P(Y<t)$. Is it equal to $P(X<t)P(t<Y)$?

Comment: @Did Please take a look at my Edit.

Comment: Of course $\{X<t\}$ and $\{t<Y\}$ are independent events if, as here, $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Please reread carefully the definition of independence of random variables in your notes.

Comment: And $P(X<t<Y)=1−P(X>t)−P(Y<t)$ is trivially wrong (I don't know what gave you the idea).

Comment: @Did I know where I got it wrong. The question I actually want to ask is: $P(X<t)$, where $t$ is a variable and satisfies $t<Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables with known distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Using the independence,
$$
P(X<t<Y)=P(\{X<t\}\cap\{t<Y\})=P(X<t)P(Y>t).
$$

Comment: i.e. $F_X(t)(1-F_Y(t))$ if $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are the cdf of $X$ and $Y$ resp.

Comment: ... in the case where $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

By calculation of integral $$\int[x<t<y]\,dF_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
Here $[x<t<y]$ denotes the function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto1$ if $x<t<y$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Note: the random variables must have a joint distribution.

---

**Edit**:

This answer was made before your edit in which $X$ and $Y$ were said to be independent.

Comment: My own answer: P(X<t<Y)=1−P(X>t)−P(T<t). Is it correct?

Comment: What is $T$ here?

Comment: sorry, T should be Y.

Comment: Your answer is not correct.

Comment: Could you please explain it?

Comment: You beter ask a new question in which you explain how you come to this result and ask what you did wrong.

Comment: sure, can I invite you to answer the new question?

Comment: I will have a look at it. Right now I have not the opportunity.